# @XmlJavaTypeAdapter w/ Inheritance

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` defined for each Exception in my exception heirarchy. I use a wrapper object for marshaling the exceptions as below:-

```
@XmlRootElement
public Wrapper<T extends BaseException> {
    T exception;
}
```

The exceptions:-

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BaseExceptionAdapter.class) {
public class BaseException extends RuntimeException {
}


@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DerivedExceptionAdapter.class) {
public class DerivedException extends BaseException {
}
```

When I try marshaling a wrapper object, JAXB by default always calls the `BaseExceptionAdapter` even if the actual exception is of type `DerivedException`. How can I force it to look for the instance type of the exception rather than the reference type.

Just to add, `package-info` / `jaxb.index` etc are as excepted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need an @XmlElementRef on your T field, to tell JAXB to look that up dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all your exception sub-types listed in package-info / jaxb.index / newInitialContext(...)?

JAX-B will look at the instance type, but I believe the sub-types need to be registered with JAX-B. It won't discover the XMLJavaTypeAdapter annotation at runtime you have to explicitly register each sub-class with JaxB.

This can also be accomplished with the @XmlSeeAlso annotation from a class that is registered with JAX-B.